# How to draw all diagonals in the n-gon from a particular vertex?

Tags: inkscape

What I'm trying to do is this[image]

I can draw them one by one, but what if I have not a 15-gon but a 1002-gon, how do I "automate" that? What tool should I use?

I've tried to use "Interpolate" tool, but diagonals aligned with the straight line, rather than the сircumscribed circle[image]

By the way, I'm using Inkscape 0.92.2

Comment: Perhaps you can look into [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/regular-polygons/)? If you have specific questions the people at tex.stackexchange.com can probably help you.

Comment: Then you should be writing the svg using some programming interface. Wether its TeX, mathematica, javascript in the browser, svg by hand or eps doe snot really matter

Comment: Note that a 1002 gon does not look very interesting in normal screen scales [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsM5d.jpg) I made the lines thin so you can see them yet even at this cale they flow into each other and make a moire pattern

Comment: Thank you @SaaruLindestøkke! Didn't know about TikZ. Now i'm studying Tkinz to workout the asnwer.

Comment: @joojaa would you mind sharing the method that you used to create that image? I suppose it might be helpful to InkUsya.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks for pointing that out, but I used it just like an enormous amount of steps, that I wouldn't do one by one.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke i wrote an [eps file with notepad and opened in my editor of choice](https://pastebin.com/aEqUfV9J) now that i think of it it seems i plotted 1021 gon

Comment: @joojaa I don't know anything about eps scripting, but can't you just post that code as an answer with some instructions on what parts of the code do?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke its not a script its a file format ;) no thst why i dindt post this as a answer

Comment: EPS stands for "Encapsulated PostScript". PostScript [is a dynamically typed, concatenative programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) according to Wikipedia. So, it's a script after all. However, that doesn't matter as it solves the problem without the question asker needing to manually connect all the lines.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke yes, its a programming language  but mostly its used as a file format. Most people dont know ist a programming language anyway, and quite many applications will open it as a image, including higher end printers. So all you need to do is dump that text in a file set the extension to EPS and ods are some program on your computer opens it as a image. So its one of those programming languages that is in fact implemented as a file format in most applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User [joojaa](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa) posted an answer in the comments but is for some reason reluctant to post it as an actual answer. To keep in line with the SE format I've therefore posted his answer below, I hope that's ok.

As the EPS format is merely a set of instructions you can use that to code your n-gon with an arbitrary number N as follows:

1. Open a text editor (e.g. notepad++, sublime text, textedit)
2. Paste in the code below.
3. Adjust the number `10` in the line `/num 10 def` (line 6, the first line after the comments) to adjust the number of corners in your n-gon.
4. Save it as a file with and `.eps` extension.
5. View it with any eps-capable viewer.

### Code

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: -40 -40 40 40
%%Creator: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa
%%EndComments

/num 10 def
/li {dup sin 30 mul exch cos 30 mul lineto} def
/lin {0 30 moveto li} def

1 1 num {
360 mul num div lin
} for
stroke 

0 30 moveto
1 1 num {
360 mul num div li
} for
stroke

%%EOF
```

### Output

This is the output for N = 40 and N = 6 (`/num 40 def` and `/num 6 def`  respectively)
[image]

### Documentation

Someone at the University of Cambridge posted [this nice documentation of the EPS language](https://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~mjr/eps.pdf). That might help interpreting what all the commands do.

### Automation

If you would like to create a set of n-gons for a series of `N`, you could create script (with any scripting language of your choosing) to change the number on line 6 and save a different eps file each time. How to do that is not in the scope of this SE.

Comment: Thank you [jooja](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/18306/joojaa) and [Saaru Lindestøkke](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/8845/saaru-lindest%c3%b8kke)